# SWIG Convert unsigned char* to 20 byte buffer Java structure

Tags: swig

I have a C function (composeKey) that has an input unsigned char* parameter ("key").  On the C side, "key" needs to be an empty 20 byte buffer structure.  I'm assuming that a Java short array with a size of 20 would be the correct Java structure to pass composeKey's "key" parameter, but I'm unsure. Maybe a byte[20] is what i need.  If that is correct, what SWIG Interface file modification is needed to generate the composeKey Java method with a short[] as input for the "key" parameter?

```
C Function:
int composeKey(const void* secret, int secret_len, unsigned char* key, int length);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution to your specific problem

Java doesn't really distinguish between `short[20]` and (e.g.) `short[21]` in its type system. You can do something that's pretty sensible quite simply though, by making the fact that the length of `key` is always 20 obvious to SWIG:

```
%module test

%include "arrays_java.i"

int func(unsigned char key[20]);
```

This can work even without changing the actual signature of your function directly - SWIG can wrap that, but have the wrapped code call a function that still takes `unsigned char*` quite sensibly:

```
%module test

%{
#include "header.h"
// fine even if it's func(unsigned char *key) in the header.
%}

%include "arrays_java.i"
int func(unsigned char key[20]);
```

If you call `func` from Java with an inappropriately sized array you'll get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` exception thrown for you automatically by the code that SWIG generates.

---

### General solution

In this specific case `"arrays_java.i"` provides a suitable typemap already. In the more general case this works by providing SWIG with a typemap for `unsigned char [ANY]` (literally write `ANY` in SWIG typemap syntax). This then gets instantiated for specific values in place of `ANY` (sort of like a template in C++), you can then access the specific value of `ANY` in your typemap using `$1_size` and supply code that the sizes gets filled in to look (some JNI details omitted for brevity) roughly like:

```
if (GetArrayLength(arg) != $1_size) {
    // Code to throw a Java Exception ...
```

Which then in the generated wrapper becomes:

```
if (GetArrayLength(arg) != 20) {
    // Code to throw a Java Exception ...
```