# How to define swig typemap for returning unsigned char* back to java

Tags: java, java-native-interface, arrays, swig, unsigned-char

I have a Java Application that calls a c library for performing crypto functions.
This is a custom library implemented in c that we need to use from some Java programs.
I need a way to define a SWIG typemap that will allow me call a function passing bytearray from Java and treat it as an unsigned character pointer in C function where c function fills data and returns it to java

Excerpt of my present unhappy interface file is as follows

```
%module  CryptoFacade

%pointer_functions(int, intp);
%pointer_functions(unsigned char, unsigned_charp);

int enCrypt(char* clearText, int clearLen,unsigned char* retCipherText, int *retCipherLen);
```

---

And Excerpt from my unhappy Java code is as follows. In the code below I expected that the call to enCrypt function will give me a buffer but it gives me a "short" as per generated code. (See comments in the code)

---

```
class MainLoader {
static {
     System.loadLibrary("dccasecuJ"); //Load my crypto library
}

 public static void main(String[] args) {

 // Define the parameters to be passed by reference 
 SWIGTYPE_p_int retCipherLen=CryptoFacade.new_intp();
 SWIGTYPE_p_unsigned_char retCipherText =
            CryptoFacade.new_unsigned_charp();

CryptoFacade myFacade=new CryptoFacade();   

// Call crypto library function. First two are value parameters, next two are return
myFacade.enCrypt("STRING-TO-ENCRYPT", 17, retCipherText, retCipherLen);

// The length I get back in fourth parameter is just fine 
int gotLen= CryptoFacade.intp_value(retCipherLen); 

//The value I get for the Ciphertext though is a "short" ... no good 
// I need a byte[] in java that has the ciphertext
short gotText= CryptoFacade.unsigned_charp_value(retCipherText);
```

I guess I should change my interface definition to something like below where I make my third parameter a jbytearray and then I got to implement a typemap that will copy the contents pointed to by unsigned character pointer in C program to a java bytearray.

I am perfectly fine if I have to specify the length of content to 256 bytes, because handling arbitrary lengths may be tricky.

Can someone point me to place where I can find such a typemap (I am new to SWIG and have no experience in writing typemaps)

```
%module  CryptoFacade

%pointer_functions(int, intp);
%pointer_functions(unsigned char, unsigned_charp);

int enCrypt(char* clearText, int clearLen, jbyteArray retCipherText, int *retCipherLen);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do work with byte arrays in Java is to use `%array_class` (or `%array_functions`) which is like `%pointer_functions` but for an entire array, not just a single element. I put together a complete example for you, using this header file as a test:

```
inline void foo(unsigned char *bytearr) {
  bytearr[0] = 1;
  bytearr[1] = 2;
  bytearr[2] = 3;
  bytearr[3] = 100;
}
```

We can wrap this with SWIG with:

```
%module test

%{
#include "test.h"
%}

%include <carrays.i>
%array_class(unsigned char,ByteArr);

%include "test.h"

// Emit Java code to automatically load the shared library
%pragma(java) jniclasscode=%{
  static {
    try {
        System.loadLibrary("test");
    } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
      System.err.println("Native code library failed to load. \n" + e);
      System.exit(1);
    }
  }
%}
```

I also put together some Java to exercise this function:

```
public class run {
  public static void main(String[] argv) {
    ByteArr arr = new ByteArr(4); // Initial size 4
    // You could set some values before passing in if you wanted to.
    test.foo(arr.cast());
    System.out.println(arr.getitem(0) + ", " + arr.getitem(1) + ", " + arr.getitem(2) + ", " + arr.getitem(3));
  }
}
```

which compiled and ran. Note that `unsigned char` in C or C++ is represented in Java as `short` - Java doesn't have any unsigned types, so the smallest type which fits the range 0-255 is a short. `byte` doesn't cover it by default. (You could play games re-mapping `unsigned char` to `byte` in other ways but that's far from intuitive so the default is not to).

You can do more advanced things if you want. For example [if you know the size of the array you can use `arrays_java.i`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8319894/168175). [This example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9934059/swig-technique-to-wrap-unsigned-binary-data/9979340#9979340) creates typemaps using JNI for returning an array of `unsigned char`. [This example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10949956/168175) shows how to pass an array in to a function using JNI typemaps. (It's using `long` instead of `byte`, but the it's literally a search and replace to change that).

Comment: A supplimentary question - in the example in http://stackoverflow.com/a/10949956/168175 you mentioned that I can write a typemap that takes length as an argument - for example

Comment: @YogeshDevi - I'll write up an answer to that later hopefully

Comment: Flexo, a supplimentary question - in the example in http://stackoverflow.com/a/10949956/168175 you mentioned that I can write a typemap that takes length as an argument. Can you please give an example of a typemaps that will allow me to call a c function foo( char * buf , int buflen) from java ,  where I use buflen to define how many bytes I copy either way (Java to c and C to Java ?  Thanks again :-)

Comment: @YogeshDevi - Since it got quite long I asked and answered that as [here in my own Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11584599/168175).