# SWIG: converting java:byte[] to C:(void*)

Tags: java, c, type-conversion, byte, swig

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pass an array to a wrapped function as pointer+size or range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11584599/pass-an-array-to-a-wrapped-function-as-pointersize-or-range)

I'm currently learning [swig](http://www.swig.org/) and I'm playing with the C api to wrap stdio.h. So, my wig file look like this:

```
%module jstdio

%{
#include <stdio.h>
%}

FILE* fopen(const char* path, const char*  mode);
int fclose( FILE* fp);
size_t fread(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream);
size_t fwrite(const void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb,FILE *stream);
```

My java class would be:

```
public class CFile
   {
   private SWIGTYPE_p_JSTDIO ptr;
   public CFile(String path,String mode) throws IOException
         {
         this.ptr=jstdio.fopen(path,mode);
         if(this.ptr==null) ... //throw...
         }
   (...)
   public int write(byte[] array,int pos,int length) throws IOException
        {
        (... here I should call jstdio.fwrite )
        }
   public int read(byte[] array,int pos,int length) throws IOException
        {
        (... here I should call jstdio.fread )
        }
   (...)
   }
```

now, for read/write, what is the correct way to tell swig to convert my java array of byte to a (void*) ptr ? I think I need to use a %typemap but I don't get the right way to use it ?

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/a/11584600/168175 cover it? If not I'll write up an answer here later.

Comment: yes! I didn't find it. Thank you.