# SWIG/Java get buffer of unknown size from C++

Tags: java, c++, swig

I have a C++ function
`foo(unsigned char*& ptr)`
that creates a buffer and fills it with binary data and sets ptr to point to it.
I need to get the buffer's contents from Java.

To clarify, the C++ code can be used like this:

```
unsigned char* ptr;
foo(ptr);
//now ptr points to a buffer, do what you want, eg
x=ptr[1];
```

Using `arrays_java.i` will not work because SWIG needs to know the array size in advance. I also tried the built-in typemap NIOBUFFER for `unsigned char*` modified for `unsigned char*&` but that presented problems with the generated C++ wrapper code, where the JVM crashed when attempting to use it. I also don't think using `carrays.i` as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11564334/how-to-define-swig-typemap-for-returning-unsigned-char-back-to-java) will work either because the parameter is `unsigned char*&`, not just `unsigned char*`, but I haven't tried this yet. (**EDIT** using `%array_functions (int * Iarr)` for a test function

```
void test(int*& ia)
{
ia[0]=1;
...
}
```

results in a JVM crash with EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION as happened with the NIOBUFFER typemap)

Is there a way to get the buffer's size from the C++/JNI wrapper code and then create a Java array of known size from within the JNI code so I can leverage `arrays_java.i`?

Is there a way to use NIOBUFFER, possibly with modifications to its typemap and/or the generated C++ wrapper?

Is there a way to treat some `type*&` as a `type*`so I can use `carrays.i`?

Because both the NIOBUFFER typemap and `array_functions` crashed the JVM, I have a feeling that the root of my problem is the `type*&` parameter and that a way to solve this will allow either of those two options. How do I do this?

Comment: How would you use the buffer if your main program was in C and you were not using JNI, without knowing the size?

Comment: There is no way to create a Java array without knowing the size of the array.

Comment: I specifically said I am using SWIG, which generated JNI code and that one possibility I am considering is to modify that code so that it does what I want. This could include getting the C++ buffer size and replacing the array passed from Java with another of appropriate size and handing that one back out to Java.

And of course, I am interested in simpler approaches.

Comment: Before considering `SWIG` or `JNI` how does the `C++` function that calls `foo(ptr);` know what size the returned array is?

Comment: I assume you know the size of the buffer. Is it documented? Is it also reference returned? How would a C++ user know the size of the buffer?

Comment: The data that the function fills in the buffer is a file type with header information including its size. That is how the caller of `foo` can know the size of the buffer.

Comment: that is, after `foo` is called, the caller can use the passed-in pointer to examine the buffer's header to find out how big the buffer is

Comment: Create a function with an `char**` argument. Your C program will allocat. Create an `in` and an `argout` typemaps to convert the argument into a return type and free any temporary char array. There should be plenty of such examples out there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come up with a solution. Assuming the same function `foo` in my question:

1. Write a function, say `bar`, that creates a local pointer, passes it into `foo`, and returns it. In this case, `bar` would be

   `unsigned char* bar()
   {
    unsigned char* ptr;
    foo(ptr);
    return ptr;
   }`
2. In SWIG: Use `%array_classes` , ie, `array_class(unsigned char, ShortArray)`
3. Create an instance of the array class via the pointer returned from `bar` by using `frompointer`. 
   `ShortArray sa = ShortArray.frompointer(example.bar())`

This bypasses the headache of getting SWIG to work with `type*&` as an argin/out, since you are now dealing with ordinary pointers and arrays which SWIG handles just fine "out of the box". It also allows the Java side to receive a buffer of arbitrary size and also provides more Java-like syntax.

Comment: Unless ``foo` is making the pointer `ptr` point to a buffer which is either static or disposed of properly when your library exits, you leak memory. I solved your problem 1000 times in Python, if you would like to see this solution, I can give it to you.

Comment: Well, the Java side has in `array_classes.i` the function `delete`. Will that prevent the memory leak?

Comment: There is almost a complete example of what you are trying to do in the SWIG manual in the Java section..

Comment: Do you mean 25.10.6, "Using typemaps to return arguments"?.

The manual doesn't elaborate on `delete` from `array_class`. Does it delete the C pointer that the Java array class was created from via `frompointer`? Or will I have to use typemaps to prevent the memory leak?

Comment: No, 25.10.4. in the SWIG 3.0 documentation. An array of strings are returned as a Java String Array. It does a little more than you need, but you can change to a length 1 array or a single String object.